# Why does this crash?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, crash, nsmutablearray, nsuserdefaults

I made a class. This is the h file.

```
//  MyClass.h
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>


@interface MyClass : NSObject <NSCoding> {
    NSString *string1;
    NSString *string2;

}
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *string1;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *string2;

@end
```

This is the m file.

```
//  MyClass.m
#import "MyClass.h"


@implementation MyClass
@synthesize string1, string2;

- (void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder;
{
    if (self = [super init]){
        [coder encodeObject:string1 forKey:@"string1"];
        [coder encodeObject:string2 forKey:@"string2"]; 
    }

}

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder;
{
    self = [[MyClass alloc] init];
    if (self != nil)
    {
        string1 = [coder decodeObjectForKey:@"string1"];
        string2 = [coder decodeObjectForKey:@"string2"];

    }   
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidUnload {
    self.string1 = nil;
    self.string2 = nil;
}


- (void)dealloc {
    [super dealloc];
    [string1 release];
    [string2 release];
}


@end
```

I created an array of these objects like this:

```
MyClass *object1 = [[MyClass alloc] init];
object1.string1 = @"object1 string1";
object1.string2 = @"string1 string2";
MyClass *object2 = [[MyClass alloc] init];
object2.string1 = @"object2 string1";
object2.string2 = @"object2 string2";
theArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:object1, object2, nil];
```

Then I saved the array like this:

```
  [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:theArray] forKey:@"savedArray"];
```

Then I loaded the array from disk like this.

```
NSUserDefaults *currentDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSData *dataRepresentingSavedArray = [currentDefaults objectForKey:@"savedArray"];
    if (dataRepresentingSavedArray != nil)
    {
        NSArray *oldSavedArray = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:dataRepresentingSavedArray];
        if (oldSavedArray != nil)
        {
            theArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:oldSavedArray];
        }
        else {

            theArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        }


    }
```

The program crashes when it gets to this line in `- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`

```
cell.textLabel.text = [[theArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] string1];
```

Why does it crash there? It doesn't crash if I don't load the array from NSUserDefaults. However, I don't see anything I did wrong with saving or loading the array.

Edit: 
I can also make it crash with this line of code:

```
NSLog(@"%@", [[theArray objectAtIndex:0] string1]) ;
```

Comment: What exception caused the crash? Did you make sure that `theArray` wasn't out of index, e.g. `- tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:` was correctly set?

Comment: No error messages are given, the program just exits. If I use the debugger I see the message Program received signal:  “EXC_BAD_ACCESS”. tableView:numberOfRowsInSection returns 1.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In addition to cobbal's excellent points, your `initWithCoder:` method isn't using setters and therefore the strings aren't being retained. When you try to access `string1` at your crash line, that string has probably already been released. Do this in `initWithCoder:` instead:

```
self.string1 = [coder decodeObjectForKey:@"string1"];
self.string2 = [coder decodeObjectForKey:@"string2"];
```

To address cobbal's first point, don't do any init at all in `encodeWithCoder:`. Just encode your object. Check out [Apple's Archives and Serializations Programming Guide for Cocoa](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Archiving/Archiving.html) for more details about encoding and decoding objects.

Comment: Thanks, that solved it! Why aren't setters and getters used if the strings have already been synthesized?

Comment: @awakeFromNib because self.string1 is actually syntactic sugar for [self setString1]. Writing string1 cannot call that method, how could it know it is a method?

Comment: The @synthesize statement effectively writes the setter and getter methods for you; it's still up to you to call them. As ustun points out, self.string1=@"z" gets replaced by [self setString1:@"z"] whereas string1=@"z" just sets string1 without calling the setter.

Answer (score 3):

A few things jump out at me

- you're calling `init` in `encodeWithCoder:`. since you're not initializing anything here you should not be changing `self`
- you're calling `alloc` in `initWithCoder:`. Once you're in an init method you shouldn't have to call alloc, just call `self = [super init]`.
- you have a `viewDidUnload` method. Even if this were called in an NSObject subclass, you probably don't want to get rid of your data when the view is unloaded.
- you're calling `[super dealloc]` at the beginning of your dealloc method. It should go at the end.

Comment: What should I do about your first point? Should I just delete if (self = [super init])? I tried that, and it didn't work. I made changes according to your other points and none of them fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't read all of your code, so I am not sure if this is the problem, but in `dealloc` you should call `[super dealoc]` only after releasing the instance variables.

Answer (score 0):

If it crashes due to being out of bounds, check that your UITableViewController correctly implements

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
```

and

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
```

to reflect the NSArray you're using as data source.